# Java throws IndexOutOfBounds when editing observableList

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, observablelist

My teacher taught me that when I update an object in my Observable List, it automatically detects the changes and notifies the observer. However when I try to update a person in the list, it throws an index out of bounds exception. I can't figure out what is going wrong.

```
private ObservableList<ClubPersoon> personen;

public void updatePersoon(ClubPersoon editPerson) {
        GenericDaoJpa.openPersistency();
        GenericDaoJpa.em.getTransaction().begin();
        UpdatePersoonValues(editPerson);
        GenericDaoJpa.em.getTransaction().commit();
        GenericDaoJpa.closePersistency();
}

private void UpdatePersoonValues(ClubPersoon currentLid) {
        int index = personen.indexOf(personen.stream().filter(p -> p.getId() == currentLid.getId()).findFirst());
        personen.get(index).setVoornaam(currentLid.getVoornaam());
        personen.get(index).setAchternaam(currentLid.getAchternaam());
        personen.get(index).setEmail(currentLid.getEmail());
        personen.get(index).setEmailOuders(currentLid.getEmailOuders());
        personen.get(index).setEmail(currentLid.getEmail());
        personen.get(index).setTelefoonNummer(currentLid.getTelefoonNummer());
        personen.get(index).setGeboorteDatum(currentLid.getGeboorteDatum());
        personen.get(index).setBackupTelefoon(currentLid.getBackupTelefoon());
        personen.get(index).setScore(currentLid.getScore());
        personen.get(index).setGeslacht(currentLid.getGeslacht());
        personen.get(index).setRijksregisternummer(currentLid.getRijksregisternummer());
        personen.get(index).setRol(currentLid.getRol());
        personen.get(index).setGraad(currentLid.getGraad());
        personen.get(index).setLocatie(currentLid.getLocatie());
        personen.get(index).setVerwachteDagen(currentLid.getVerwachteDagen());
        personen.get(index).setActiviteiten(currentLid.getActiviteiten());
    }
```

This is the error's path:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at java.base/java.util.Vector.elementData(Vector.java:761)
    at java.base/java.util.Vector.get(Vector.java:782)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.get(ObservableListWrapper.java:89)
    at domein.Club.UpdatePersoonValues(Club.java:143)
    at domein.Club.updatePersoon(Club.java:80)
    at domein.DomeinController.updatePersoon(DomeinController.java:113)
    at gui.PersoonDetailController.handleBtnOpslaan(PersoonDetailController.java:186)
```

Comment: Check `index` before using it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the documentation of [`List.indexOf(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)), that method returns `-1` if the `List` does not contain the object passed as an argument. Trying to access a `List` via an index of `-1` will always cause an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` (or `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, since you appear to be wrapping a `Vector`).

That said, the way you've currently implemented your method will **always** cause `-1` to be returned. Notice the signature of `indexOf`; it accepts `Object`, not `E`. That means you can pass any object you want to that method and your code will compile. Now take a look at the return type of [`Stream.findFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst())—it returns `Optional<T>`. In other words, your code is equivalent to:

```
Optional<ClubPerson> optional = personen.stream().filter(p -> p.getId() == currentLid.getId()).findFirst();
int index = personen.indexOf(optional);
...
```

As `personen` is an `ObservableList<ClubPerson>`, it can't contain any `Optional<ClubPerson>` elements.

It's not exactly clear why you attempt to find the `ClubPerson` in the list, then query the index of that element, only to simply access the list again with said index to modify the `ClubPerson` you've already found. Why not just modify the `ClubPerson` directly? You could even use [`Optional.ifPresent(Consumer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent(java.util.function.Consumer)).

```
personen.stream().filter(p -> p.getId() == currentLid.getId()).findFirst().ifPresent(p -> {
    p.setVoornaam(currentLid.getVoornaam());
    p.setAchternaam(currentLid.getAchternaam());
    p.setEmail(currentLid.getEmail());
    p.setEmailOuders(currentLid.getEmailOuders());
    p.setEmail(currentLid.getEmail());
    p.setTelefoonNummer(currentLid.getTelefoonNummer());
    p.setGeboorteDatum(currentLid.getGeboorteDatum());
    p.setBackupTelefoon(currentLid.getBackupTelefoon());
    p.setScore(currentLid.getScore());
    p.setGeslacht(currentLid.getGeslacht());
    p.setRijksregisternummer(currentLid.getRijksregisternummer());
    p.setRol(currentLid.getRol());
    p.setGraad(currentLid.getGraad());
    p.setLocatie(currentLid.getLocatie());
    p.setVerwachteDagen(currentLid.getVerwachteDagen());
    p.setActiviteiten(currentLid.getActiviteiten());
});
```

If the element not being present in the list is an error, you can instead use something like [`Optional.orElseThrow(Supplier)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow(java.util.function.Supplier)) or [`Optional.orElseThrow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow()) (Java 10+).

```
ClubPerson p = personen.stream().filter(p -> p.getId() == currentLid.getId())
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow(); // throws NoSuchElementException if element not found
// set properties of "p"...
```